# python logging not outputting date/time

Tags: python, logging

This is the code that I'm running:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename="..\logs\demologs.log",
    filemode="a",
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s : %(message)s",
    datefmt="%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p",
)


class DemoLogging1:
    def add_numbers(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def multiply_numbers(self, a, b):
        return a * b


dl = DemoLogging1()
sum_result = dl.add_numbers(3, 5)
logging.debug("debug: addition of numbers is: {}".format(sum_result))
logging.info("info: addition of numbers is: {}".format(sum_result))
logging.warning("warning: addition of numbers is: {}".format(sum_result))
logging.error("error: addition of numbers is: {}".format(sum_result))
logging.critical("critical: addition of numbers is: {}".format(sum_result))

multiply_result = dl.multiply_numbers(3, 5)
```

This won't output the date and time as far as the formatting next to each logging error statement. Why?

Comment: thanks for the editing suggestion. But can someone please answer my question, line spacing is irrelevant to what I asked, the code was perfectly readable.  But thank you, always looking to improve.

Comment: What's wrong with the format? I get: `11/23/21 09:23:42 AM` which is `%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p` as defined. What is the expected output?

Comment: im using spyder with python 3.7.9 and its not giving me any date time output to the console. Could be an error with my computer or an error with spyder or maybe the python thats installed?

Comment: If you are dealing with the console, try specifying the console output. I've provided an example.

Comment: if you dont mind my asking, what compiler are you guys using to run this, since yours is working.

Comment: the problem was the compiler i was using, neither spyder nor sublime would run it correctly, once i installed pycharm it finally worked, not sure what the deal was with the other 2 compilers, anyways, doesnt matter. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm not sure about spyder IDE (I'm not using it), maybe you have to set configuration for logs there. Just try to run your code using `python <your-file.py>` from the console. I'm using 3.7.11 but that doesn't matter. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting output to the console because you are not specifying the console stream. It just goes to your file.

To output to both console and file, try this:

```py
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s : %(message)s",
    datefmt="%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p",
    handlers=[
        logging.StreamHandler(),
        logging.FileHandler("test.log", "a"),
    ],
)
```

Comment: I got it working that same day, I meant what IDE were you using, and I know python version doesn't matter, the IDE I was using was the problem. Switching to pycharm fixed it. The code you gave me worked,  really appreciate it.. Thanks!!! :)